# Maple: Accessing the solutions of solve when solving for multiple functions

Tags: function, linear-algebra, maple

When I want to solve a set of linear equations for two functions, e.g.

```
solutions := solve({f(x)=x,g(x)=x},{f(x),g(x)});
```

what exactly can I do to work with the solutions as functions themselves in maple?

The only thing which I was able to do was

```
f_solution := x2 -> subs(x=x2, rhs(solutions[1]))
```

But that is ugly in many aspects. First, this trivial substitution `x->x2` seems necessary, without it will not work. Second, the construct `rhs(solutions[1])` is very bad, as it is not possible to control the order of the solutions. Consequently everytime I modify my equations, I would have to check manually, if the index `[1]` is still correct.

Is there a clean and standard way to extract the functions from the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
solutions := solve({2*f(x)=sin(x),g(x)/3=cos(x)},{f(x),g(x)});

           /       1                        \ 
          { f(x) = - sin(x), g(x) = 3 cos(x) }
           \       2                        /
```

and now, with `f_solution` as an expression,

```
f_solution := eval(f(x), solutions);

                        1       
                        - sin(x)
                        2
```

or with `f_solution` as a procedure,

```
f_solution := unapply( eval(f(x), solutions), x);

                         1       
                    x -> - sin(x)
                         2
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be exactly what i need, will try it out tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `assign`. It can fix the solutions you obtain in your calculation

```
> restart:
> solutions := solve({f(x)=x,g(x)=x},{f(x),g(x)});

                  solutions := {f(x) = x, g(x) = x}

> assign(%);
> f(x);

                                  x
```

You could also just try `subs` like this

```
> restart:
> solutions := solve({f(x)=x,g(x)=x},{f(x),g(x)});

                  solutions := {f(x) = x , g(x) = x}

> subs(solutions,f(x));
                                  x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, it would be nice, to assign the solution to a **new** symbol `f_solution` instead, to keep my project clean.